# KafkaConnect fails to load plugin

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium, strimzi

I'm deploying KafkaCluster, KafkaConnect on K8s by using Strimzi.

- Strimzi Operator Cluster image: quay.io/strimzi/operator:0.26.1
- Kafka image: quay.io/strimzi/kafka:0.26.1-kafka-3.0.0.

I'm trying to setting KafkaConnector which connects to Postgres DB.

These are my steps:

1. Build a new KafkaConnect from this image 'quay.io/strimzi/kafka:0.26.1-kafka-3.0.0'. This new image has plugin which I download from this link 'https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/connectors/postgresql.html#postgresql-deployment'
2. I run this new image on K8s, then exec into KafkaConnect container. It has plugin correctly ('/opt/kafka/plugins/debezium/debezium-connector-postgres'):
   [image]
3. I create KafkaConnector which refers to class 'io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector':

```
kind: "KafkaConnector"
metadata:
  name: dev-approvalflowservice-connector
  labels:
    strimzi.io/cluster: postgres-connect-cluster-1
spec:
  class: io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector
  tasksMax: 2
  config:
    database.hostname: 10.14.101.204
    database.port: "5432"
    database.user: "debezium"
    database.password: "debezium"
    database.dbname: "approvalflowservice"
    database.server.name: "approvalflowservice"
    plugin.name: "pgoutput"
    slot.name: "approvalflowserviceslot"
    truncate.handling.mode: "include"
    table.include.list: "public.approval_flow"
```

4. The problem is KafkaConnect fail to load the Plugin which I already added in to new KafkaConnect image. Log from KafkaConnect: [log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1j334YubuwW935NYTlqEzCOSIwdDRfgWp/view?usp=sharing)

**Update**

5. I tried to change the location of plugin inside the new KafkaConnect image ('/opt/kafka/plugins/debezium-connector-postgres') :
   [image]
6. The problem is the same: [log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mzPJxEkmzuNtHXv0EePmtX4CDta56Taf/view?usp=sharing)

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

In your logs, you have

```
Loading plugin from: /opt/kafka/plugins/debezium
```

But, since your plugin is installed into a subfolder, no Postgres class is being listed as loaded.

Make sure that the plugin path only has one folder between the path you've defined and where the JARs are available. e.g. install to `/opt/kafka/plugins/debezium-connector-postgres`

You can also issue a `GET /connector-plugins` HTTP request to the Connect API to list the available connectors for the cluster before you create one.

Comment: Thank you. I tried as same as you suggested, but it keeps the same issue.

Comment: Maybe the file permissions are off for that folder? For example, if the image runs as non-root, then that folder's files cannot be read (and your image shows you running `ls` as the `kafka` user). You could also try running the image outside of k8s to verify its behavior. Otherwise,  you should be able to report Debezium issues here https://issues.redhat.com/projects/DBZ/issues/